# log in I tried different codes almost always same happening does that maybe has anything with cookies

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I tried different codes almost always same happening does that maybe has anything with cookies.

I have this code which always show doesn't matter what count is

```
echo "Hai " . $email . " 
"; 
echo "Checking 
"; 
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";  


     <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="form1" style="width: 95%; margin: 0 2.5%" novalidate>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="ea">Email Address:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                  <DIV align="left"><input type="text" name="email" id="email_addr_existing" class="input-large valid"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="pa">Password:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <DIV align="left"><input type="password"  name="password" id="login_password" class="input-large valid"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls" id="exist_wait"></div>
      </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label"></label>
        <div class="controls">
          <tr valign="baseline">
        <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        <td> <DIV align="left"><input type="submit" name="Submit1" class="submit" value="Submit"></div></td>
      </tr>

   <?php  
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])){ 

     $conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");  
    if(mysqli_connect_error()) {  
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    } 
    $conn->select_db('');   


if (isset($_POST['email']) and isset($_POST['password'])){ 
//3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables. 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$password = $_POST['password']; 
//3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not 


$query = "SELECT email,password FROM `users1` COUNT WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
//3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user. 
if ($count =0){ 
echo "Wrong email or password";   
} 

}elseif($count >0){ 
//3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message. 
echo"Welcome."; 
} 

//3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message 

}else{ 
}     

echo "Hai " . $email . " 
"; 
echo "Checking 
"; 
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>"; 


    ?>
```

Table structure:

```
     CREATE TABLE `users1` ( 
      `user_id` int(5) NOT NULL, 
      `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL, 
      `email` varchar(35) NOT NULL, 
      `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL 
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

    -- 
    -- Dumping data for table `users1` 
    --
```

I tried different codes almost always same happening does that maybe has anything with cookies.

Comment: You don't get any errors? `FROM \`users1\` COUNT WHERE` seems like it should throw an error. Also you are open to SQL injections, parameterize. Additionally don't store plain text passwords.

Comment: `if ($count =0){` is another issue, that will always be true because you are assigning the variable to `0`.

Comment: Your HTML has problems. You have `<form>` without `</form>`, you have `<tr>` and `<td>` that isn't in `<table>`.

Comment: no errors                                                                                                           
 if ($count =0){ is another issue, that will always be true because you are assigning the variable to 0. – user3783243 26 mins ago  what i should do put change  if ($count >0)

Comment: added this same thing</form>

Comment: Well, `>` would work but that is checking that you have more than 0 records. If you want to check for `0` use `==` or `===`. Single `=` is an assignment. You need to use `@` for notifications to be sent.

Comment: if                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                         add $ on email an password like this          SELECT `password`,`email` FROM `users1` COUNT WHERE `email`=`$email`AND `password`=`$password`                                                
          getting error unknown column

Comment: Please update the question. Though that looks like it is still invalid SQL.. `COUNT WHERE` is not valid SQL, what are you trying to do there count something, make an alias, other? Also looks like you are using backticks for encapsulation of strings, that will be invalid (and should be parameterized).